# Move clicked slide item to extreme left

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create a slide (in the future will turn into a slide of buttons) where when the user clicks on an item, it scrolls all the items making the clicked into the first one.

The way I'm moving the slide is by getting the distance between it and the left side of the screen:

`let leftDistance = slide.getBoundingClientRect().left`

and then translate it

`` slideTrack.style.transform = `translateX(-${leftDistance}px ``

As you can see below, it actually runs for the first time, but when you click again, it doesn't.

Is there a clever way to move the clicked item to left?

```js
const slideTrack = document.querySelector(".slide-track");
const slideItems = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");



slideItems.forEach(slide => {
        slide.addEventListener('click', () =>{
            //gets the distance to left side of window
            let leftDistance = slide.getBoundingClientRect().left
            //animation time
            slideTrack.style.transition = `transform 1000ms ease`
            //move slide left according to distance
            slideTrack.style.transform = `translateX(-${leftDistance}px`
        })
        
    })
```

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  background: #E3E3E3;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}
.slider .slide-track {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(250px * 30);
}
.slider .slide {
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide-track">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/2.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/3.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/4.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/5.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/6.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/7.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/2.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/3.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/4.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/5.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/6.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/7.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sum other distances of elements but can't go back :D maybe this is what you want.

```js
const slideTrack = document.querySelector(".slide-track");
const slideItems = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
let totalDistance = 0;


slideItems.forEach(slide => {
        slide.addEventListener('click', () =>{
            //gets the distance to left side of window
            let leftDistance = slide.getBoundingClientRect().left
            totalDistance += leftDistance
            //animation time
            slideTrack.style.transition = `transform 1000ms ease`
            //move slide left according to distance
            slideTrack.style.transform = `translateX(-${totalDistance}px`
        })
        
})
```

Comment: That's actually an excellent beggining, it will work if I change the `overflow: hidden` to `scroll`, and will be perfect if I make it infinite.